# Accessing nested list in pyarrow table

Tags: pyarrow

I am trying to do some data analysis with pyarrow.
While trying to convert pyarrrow table from one schema to another but got below error.

From

```
 {
  ...
 'b' : [ {'c' : 'c1'}  ]
  ...
 }
```

To

```
 {
  ...
 'b' : ['c1']
  ...
 }
```

Code:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

msg = [{'a': 'a1', 'b': [{'c': 'c1'}], 'd': [{'e': 'e1'}]}, {'a': 'a2', 'b': [{'c': 'c2'}, {'c': 'c3'}], 'd': [{'e': 'e2'}]}]
my_table = pa.Table.from_pylist(msg)
ds.dataset(my_table).to_table(columns={'b': ds.field('b', 'c')})
```

Error

```
ArrowInvalid: No match for FieldRef.Nested(FieldRef.Name(b) FieldRef.Name(c)) in a: string
b: list<item: struct<c: string>>
d: list<item: struct<e: string>>
```

How to access underlying list of key: 'b' ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access a nested field from a list of struct, using the dataset API.

You can do it manually using `pyarrow.compute`:

```py
import pyarrow.compute as pc

batches = []

for batch in ds.dataset(my_table).scanner(columns=["b"]).scan_batches():
    record_batch = batch.record_batch
    flat_c = pc.struct_field(
        pc.list_flatten(record_batch['b']),
        [record_batch['b'].type.value_type.get_field_index('c')]
    )
    list_c = pa.ListArray.from_arrays(record_batch['b'].offsets, flat_c)
    batches.append(list_c)
    
pa.concat_arrays(batches)
```